# What can affect keyboard focus html?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I am trying to put together some accessibility examples for work.  One of the checkpoints I need to present is key board focus.

I know how assure controls gain keyboard focus, but I can not figure out what would cause a control to be non-focusable.

The only thing I have had success with is using an invalid index for tabIndex. (TabIndex = "-2").  I would prefer not to use this because this is not really an true example of keyboard trap.

I know how to make a field non focusable.  What I am trying to find, is something that causes a field to be non focusable unintentionally.

Comment: What is a keyboard trap? Hardly it is a good example of accessibility.

Comment: Keyboard trap is where you can not use the functionality via keyboard only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Explicitly setting it to be outside sequential focus navigation by using a negative number (as per [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute))
- Calling `AnHTMLElementNode.blur()` on the target element or an element before it
- Calling `AnHTMLElementNode.focus()` in such a way that another element gets the focus as a reaction to something that has to be done to reach the target element in sequential navigation
- Using an element that doesn't normally do something (such as a `<span>`) and adding an `onclick` event to it.

Comment: As per OP, I was aware of setting it outside navigation.  Blur() and focus() are ways to intentionally make a field non focusable.

Your fourth point was the answer I was looking for, but it didn't work for me.

<span onClick="incorrectUpdate()"><INPUT name="num" onMouseOut="foo" value="0" ></span>

I can still gain focus on input box VIA keyboard.

Comment: You can get to the input, you can't get to the span. There is no way to trigger the "onclick" of the span without a mouse.

Comment: After trying this out,

<span onclick="showLabel()"><input type="submit" > Button</input><span>,

The click even still fires using enter (or space bar with JAWS)

Comment: I've never tested an onclick on an element wrapped around a button, but `<span onclick="showLabel()">Just some text</span>` won't provide any way to hit the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Just add disabled:

```
<input type='text' disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: `readonly` elements can still have focus, and your answer doesn't address any other focusable elements.